# Can I ask about industrial construction on DIY.SE?

Tags: discussion, scope

I know the site is called Home Improvement, and the tour says "Don't ask about... questions that are not about home improvement", but there is not a general 'construction' Stack Exchange site that I can find.

I have a question about gravel sub-bases and their appropriateness or function for an industrial (and industrial-*sized*) construction project near my office.

Can I ask about this on the DIY Stack Exchange site, or would it be considered off-topic?

Comment: Possibly [engineering.se]. I've asked in [their chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42073211#42073211)

Comment: These questions have been considered off topic in the past. The logic is usually "if you want to know about an commercial/industrial application, you should hire a professional that's trained for the task rather than asking random strangers on the internet."

Comment: @BMitch Right, and that makes total sense. My question is more along the lines of a curious bystander wondering "Why is that construction crew doing X" (for example). But I feel your response should be an answer, rather than a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it depends on the context. In your situation, it sounds to me like it could be considered on topic.  To me, it's quite similar to this question [What is better for a roof plywood or osb](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/9311/what-is-better-for-a-roof-plywood-or-osb).  You've observed some aspect of construction, and are curious why it's done that way.  To me, this seems on topic.

If you were asking how to do something on an industrial job, so that you could do it yourself and avoid paying a professional.  Then it would be off topic for sure.

Although, I agree with @Niall C.  [Engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/) may provide better answers, if this type of question is on topic there.

Comment: Thanks, looking at some of the questions in the concrete and geotechnical-engineering tags there make it look like my question would fit in. I will ask on Engineering.SE.

Comment: Just popping in to confirm that this sounds fine for Engineering, using our [foundations tag](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foundations). (And indeed it has been received well.)